# Search Filter using Linq

Tags: java, android, linq

I want to apply search filter using EditText among list in android.

For now i was using for loop(below code).

```
private List<AllAttendance> filter(List<AllAttendance> mAttendanceList, CharSequence charSequence) {

    final String text = String.valueOf(charSequence).toLowerCase();


    List<AllAttendance> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (AllAttendance attendance : mAttendanceList){

        if (attendance.getMandalName().toLowerCase().contains(text) || attendance.getSabhaName().toLowerCase().contains(text) || attendance.getSabhaDate().toLowerCase().contains(text))
            filteredList.add(attendance);
    }
    return filteredList;
}
```

The above code is working fine. But i replacing with linq n i am not getting any record n i have pre records in list.

```
    private List<AllAttendance> filter(List<AllAttendance> mAttendanceList, CharSequence charSequence) {

    final String text = String.valueOf(charSequence).toLowerCase();
    List<AllAttendance> filteredList =
            Linq.stream(mAttendanceList)
                    .where(c -> c.getSabhaName().contains(text))
                    .toList();
    return filteredList;
}
```

Comment: Linq in Java? Does it exist?

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 yup.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) doesn't even have a `where` method on it. You should use `filter` on Stream to achieve a filtering functionality.

Replace this:

```
List<AllAttendance> filteredList =
        Linq.stream(mAttendanceList)
            .where(c -> c.getSabhaName().contains(text))
            .toList();
```

with:

```
List<AllAttendance> filteredList =
        mAttendanceList.stream()
            .filter(c -> c.getSabhaName().contains(text))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```